# How to extract some specific values from HTML?

Tags: r, rvest

Im trying to use `rvest` in order to extract some values from a ASP.NET HTML element i have in R.

With selectorgadget im trying to get identify the elements i need but im unsure whether im doing it correctly:

```
main =read_html(html_detallepersona)

Name = a %>% html_elements("fieldset+ fieldset > ul~ ul+ ul li:nth-child(1)")  

paste(Name)
[1] "<li>\r\n                <span id=\"ctl00_cphMain_lblPrimerNombre\" class=\"label\">Primer Nombre(*)</span>\r\n                <input name=\"ctl00$cphMain$txtPrimerNombre\" type=\"text\" value=\"Veronica\" maxlength=\"30\" id=\"ctl00_cphMain_txtPrimerNombre\" disabled class=\"aspNetDisabled comboBox\" style=\"text-transform: capitalize;\">\n</li>"

Name %>%  html_attr("value")
[1] NA
```

I need the value itself (Veronica)

The source HTML looks like this so i dont know if the rvest approach is the right one for my case. I rely in the `input name` in order to get the desired value which is next to it.
[image]

[image]

EDIT 1:
What about a dropdown menu? Im looking for the "Contributivo" value

[image]

```
 Regimen = detallepersona %>% html_elements("#ctl00_cphMain_upAseguradora ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1) option") #%>%  html_text()

paste(Regimen)
[1] "<option value=\"0\">-Seleccione-</option>\n"           "<option selected value=\"58\">Contributivo</option>\n"
[3] "<option value=\"61\">Especial</option>\n"              "<option value=\"60\">Pobre no afiliado</option>\n"    
[5] "<option value=\"59\">Subsidiado</option>"             

Regimen %>% html_text()
[1] "-Seleccione-"      "Contributivo"      "Especial"          "Pobre no afiliado" "Subsidiado"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are selecting the `<li>` element, if you want the `value=` attribute  then you can select it with the `html_attr()` function.

```
Name %>% html_attr("value")
```

Comment: I get an `NA` when running  `Name= a %>% html_elements("fieldset+ fieldset > ul~ ul+ ul li:nth-child(1)")  %>%  html_attr("value")`

Comment: Try with `li:nth-child(2)` It's very hard to test with an image. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Let me try to upload the HTML code as its considerably big

Comment: Maybe `Name= a %>% html_elements("fieldset+ fieldset > ul~ ul+ ul li:nth-child(1) input")  %>%  html_attr("value")`

Comment: This did it! It returns the value

Comment: Would you mind helping me with one more? I just updated the question with an EDIT